# How do I install Wireshark in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: linux, wireshark

How do I install Wireshark in Red Hat Linux?

At the [Wireshark download page](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html), am I supposed to download "Standard package" for Red Hat under "Third-Party Package"? Does the Red Hat version have a GUI?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [yum](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) command to install wireshark on RHEL

```
yum install wireshark
```

and

```
yum install wireshark-gnome
```

This is probably the best way to install the products as it will install the relevant dependencies at the same time.

Comment: ... and +1 to you, as so many times before. :-)

Comment: +1 for noting there are two packages needed for the full UI

Answer (score 2):

You could download the Sourcecode from http://wiresharkdownloads.riverbed.com/wireshark/src/wireshark-1.8.0.tar.bz2.
Then you unzip the sourcecode

```
bunzip2 wireshark-1.8.0.tar.bz2
```

Then untar the file

```
tar -xvf wireshark-1.8.0
```

Then change directory into the wireshark-directory and do the usual steps for installing from source:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

or you can use the yum-way described in the comment above. Actually that might work better because there might be dependencies.

Comment: Aieee! Do not tell a Linux newbie to compile programs from source code. That's unnecessary almost 100% of the time, scares the newbies away and defeats the purpose of package managers. Anyway, the package managers & software repositories are one very big thing Linux/BSD excels at! All this said, I'll have to -1 you.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice. you are absolutely right.

Comment: I don't agree, especially with the down voting. Let the new user decide what is more appealing to him. Where would you be today if you were using just software repositories ? :)

Comment: This implies you are running `make` as root. Please don't do this! You can `./configure` & `make` unprivileged and then `sudo make install`.

Comment: I found this guide helpful: https://nullsec.us/wireshark-from-source-rhel-7/

Answer (score 1):

Just add this Fedora RHEL compatible repository (find it here: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL ) with: rpm -Uvh "http://URL/"
And then: made a classic Yum install as mentioned upper.

Comment: Wireshark isn't provided by EPEL, it is in the base repository.

Comment: Not quite true, starting from DEVOS EPEL repos you've got access to wireshark 1.8 ;-)

Comment: What is DEVOS EPEL? (A Google search was not productive. [This](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/devos/) is all I found.)